# Jquery find image in Table and check img src

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation, dom-traversal

i want to find an image in a table and then remove the image if it got a specific url.

```
 if (event.keyCode == 189) {
     $.each($('#id tr'), function(e, v) 
        {
            $(v).find('td:nth-of-type(4) img').filter(function () {
                return $(this).attr('src') === "src";
            }).remove();
        });
    }
```

i need to find that image with "src" and then remove the $(v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the image elements you need with [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
2. Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function) to get only the images you need.
3. The filter function will run for every image (`this` will always refer to the current  image's DOM element). If you return `true` from the function, the image will be included in the result set - otherwise it is omitted.
4. On the resulting set (that only includes the filtered images) call [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Something like this:

```
$(v).find('td:nth-of-type(4) img').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('src') === THE_URL_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK;
}).remove();
```

**UPDATE:**

After some clarification, it seems you want to remove the whole table row.

In this case you need to modify the code a bit:

```
$('#id tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(4) img').attr('src') === THE_URL_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK;
}).remove();
```

And a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d9BQg/).

Comment: @selfcode I cannot really read this in its current format, but is your URL really `"src"`?

Comment: @selfcode So you want to remove the whole table? Please edit your question and clarify what you really need. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: @selfcoded I am not surprised, it does not even get to my code :). Do you know that you can check the browser console to see Javascript errors? You forgot to include jQuery (left panel) and after that some kind of `AccountManager` or something like that is missing. I cannot do anything with this until you fix it, sorry.

Comment: @selfcoded There is no `#am_widget_Farm` element in your HTML. Look, I can't really debug this for you step by step. At least make an attempt, and try to find the most obvious problems. I will help if you are really stuck.

Comment: @selfcoded Hm, there is still no element with the id `am_widget_Farm`. Will be back tomorrow...

Comment: at the top of the file it is

Comment: @selfcoded It works for me now. Added the id to the table and found out that the table cell you need is not the 4th one... learn how to debug, I will not always be there to babysit. You can accept my answer with the tickmark on the left - you should do this so everyone sees your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$(v).find('td:nth-of-type(4) img[src="URL"]').remove();
```

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)